# show checked text is not working when i click on new tab

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, activerecord, checkbox

I am trying to acheive show checked value text in one div.

[image]

By default Tiffen is active so when i click on idly and puri images the text of that image is coming and showing in selected food list

But when i click on Lunch in leftside menu as shown in figure ; they have some food like: curd and fish, when i check them the text is not appearing but when i go to tiffen tab and do any check modification the lunch values are coming with tiffen

These are my codes:

Here is my section code:

```
<section>
<div class="products">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-3 rsidebar">
<div class="related-row">
    <h4 class="text-center">Food Menu</h4> 
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tiffin" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Tiffin </a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#lunch" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> <i></i> Lunch </a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#dinner" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Dinner </a></li>
    </ul>       
</div>
<div class="related-row" id="FoodSelected">
    <h4 class="text-center">Food Selected</h4> 
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a id="selectedfood"></a></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
</div>
<form id="FoodForm">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tiffin">
    <div class="products-row">
        <?php $tq=$conn->query("select * from os_dish where dish_status=1 and dish_type=1 order by id_dish ASC");
            while ($tiffen = $tq->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>  
            <div class="col-md-3"> 
                <div class="foodmenuform row text-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $tiffen['dish_name'];?>" class="Foodmenu" value="<?php echo $tiffen['dish_name'];?>" name="tifeen[]" hidden>
                    <label for="<?php echo $tiffen['dish_name'];?>"><img src="img/dish/<?php echo $tiffen['dish_image']; ?>" class="img img-responsive" /></label>
                    <h3><?php echo $tiffen['dish_name'];?></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }  ?>
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="tab-pane" id="lunch">
    <div class="products-row">
        <?php $lq=$conn->query("select * from os_dish where dish_status=1 and dish_type=2 order by id_dish ASC");
            while ($lunch = $lq->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>  
            <div class="col-md-3"> 
                <div class="foodmenuform row text-center">
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="<?php echo $lunch['dish_name'];?>" class="FoodMenu" value="<?php  echo $lunch['dish_name'];?>" name="lunch[]" hidden>
                    <label for="<?php echo $lunch['dish_name'];?>"><img src="img/dish/<?php echo $lunch['dish_image']; ?>" class="img img-responsive" /></label>
                    <h3><?php echo $lunch['dish_name'];?></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }  ?>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="FoodSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit Food Menu</button>
</form>
</section>
```

And here is my script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
$(".Foodmenu").click(function(){
var checkedFood = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
    console.log($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').serialize());
    return $(this).attr('value');
}).get().join("<br>");
$("#selectedfood").html(checkedFood);
});
</script>
```

Comment: See the browser console, the error must be displayed there..

Comment: @Shaggy even in console only tiffen values are coming Idly and puri lunch values are not coming when they selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution all the code is write but fault is in class name issue i gave small FoodMenu istead Foodmenu